# JQ Cross reference or how to replace one value with another part of the input

Tags: openstack, jq, terraform

I want to parse terraform.tfstate (where openstack provider is used), to return instance name and it's internal + floating IP (if assigned).

First select what we are interested in:

```
jq -r '.modules?[]|.resources[]?|select(.type == "openstack_compute_floatingip_v2", .type == "openstack_compute_instance_v2")' < terraform.tfstate
```

For simplicity, pre-parsed example with the above part (one FIP and one instance):

```
{
  "type": "openstack_compute_floatingip_v2",
  "depends_on": [
    "openstack_networking_router_interface_v2.management"
  ],
  "primary": {
    "id": "48b039fc-a9fa-4672-934a-32d6d267f280",
    "attributes": {
      "address": "209.66.89.143",
      "fixed_ip": "10.10.10.5",
      "id": "48b039fc-a9fa-4672-934a-32d6d267f280",
      "instance_id": "597e75e8-834d-4f05-8408-e2e6e733577e",
      "pool": "public",
      "region": "RegionOne"
    },
    "meta": {},
    "tainted": false
  },
  "deposed": [],
  "provider": "provider.openstack"
}
{
  "type": "openstack_compute_instance_v2",
  "depends_on": [
    "openstack_compute_floatingip_v2.management",
    "openstack_compute_secgroup_v2.ssh_only",
    "openstack_networking_network_v2.management"
  ],
  "primary": {
    "id": "597e75e8-834d-4f05-8408-e2e6e733577e",
    "attributes": {
      "access_ip_v4": "10.10.10.5",
      "access_ip_v6": "",
      "all_metadata.%": "1",
      "all_metadata.habitat": "sup",
      "availability_zone": "nova",
      "flavor_id": "eb36e84e-17c1-42ab-b359-4380f6f524ae",
      "flavor_name": "m1.large",
      "force_delete": "false",
      "id": "597e75e8-834d-4f05-8408-e2e6e733577e",
      "image_id": "c574aeed-e47c-4fb7-9da0-75550b76ee56",
      "image_name": "ubuntu-16.04",
      "key_pair": "vault-etcd_test_tf",
      "metadata.%": "1",
      "metadata.habitat": "sup",
      "name": "ctl01",
      "network.#": "1",
      "network.0.access_network": "false",
      "network.0.fixed_ip_v4": "10.10.10.5",
      "network.0.fixed_ip_v6": "",
      "network.0.floating_ip": "",
      "network.0.mac": "02:c6:61:f9:ee:7e",
      "network.0.name": "management",
      "network.0.port": "",
      "network.0.uuid": "f2468669-e321-4eb4-9ede-003e362a8988",
      "region": "RegionOne",
      "security_groups.#": "1",
      "security_groups.1845949017": "vault-etcd_test_ssh_only",
      "stop_before_destroy": "false"
    },
    "meta": {
      "e2bfb730-ecaa-11e6-8f88-34363bc7c4c0": {
        "create": 1800000000000,
        "delete": 1800000000000,
        "update": 1800000000000
      }
    },
    "tainted": false
  },
  "deposed": [],
  "provider": "provider.openstack"
}
```

Required is to take from `"type": "openstack_compute_floatingip_v2"` replace `.primary.attributes.address` and `.fixed_ip` and from corresponding `.instance_id` the `.name`.

So, sth like:

```
{"address": "209.66.89.143",
"fixed_ip": "10.10.10.5",
"name": "ctl01"}
```

Well, I came with an idea while using walk, but miss how to actually assign the proper value from corresponding instance id:

```
jq -r "$(cat floating.jq)" terraform.tfstate
```

floating.jq:

```
def walk(f):
      . as $in
      | if type == "object" then
          reduce keys[] as $key
            ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
      elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
      else f
      end;
.modules?[]|.resources[]?|select(.type == 
    "openstack_compute_floatingip_v2", .type == 
    "openstack_compute_instance_v2")|
    .primary|walk( if  type == "object" and .attributes.address then 
    .attributes.instance_id |= "REFERRED VALUE HERE") else . end)
```

Comment: Why not just use a Terraform output instead of trying to parse the JSON state file?

Comment: You can use [`terraform state show`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/show.html) to get a list of all relevant information for one resource. This might be significantly easier to parse.

Comment: tf output is fine but requires proper formatting as well, I am writing an module to transform the .tfstate data to another config, so IP's just a subset things I am looking to grab from it

Comment: `terraform state show` mostly gives me data I already have, I can go to that level and play with that, but the question is how to replace in one quere, value of `instance_id` with the content of of the "record" where `id = instance_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the two related objects are in a file named two.json.  Then one way to merge the information from both objects is using the `-s` command-line option, e.g.

```
jq -s '
  (.[0].primary.attributes | {address, fixed_ip})
  + {name: .[1].primary.attributes.name}' two.json
```

#### Output

With your example input, the output would be:

```
{
  "address": "209.66.89.143",
  "fixed_ip": "10.10.10.5",
  "name": "ctl01"
}
```

Comment: Nice, usable, but assume this: ```{"id": "nic_record", "attributes": {"address": "111", "name_id": "bbb"}}``` and you want to substitue/refference name id from ```{{"id": "aaa", "attributes": {"name"aaa"}}},{"id": "aaa", "attributes": {"name"bbb"}}}}```  But select should resolve that.

Comment: Neither the original question nor the comment is very clear (at least to me).  I would suggest you try to follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible, and maybe ask a new SO question.